# What is a good way to get a value in a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have this code:

```
object M {
  implicit class Obj(str: List[_]) {
    def mm(other: String) = macro Test.impl
  }
}

//macro
//in macro i would get a `str` argument with actual value which pass into Obj
//
object Test {
  def impl(c: Context)(other: c.Expr[String]) = { 
    import c.universe._
    ???
    reify{}
  }
}
```

At the moment, I use

```
c.prefix.tree {
  case ....
}
```

But is there a better choice available? Because at compile time, I have a full tree for the class and there may be available something like this:

```
c.prefix.actualType.someMethodForInitialize.str //get `str` from object
```

Is this possible or are there others?

Example:

```
List("a", "b", "c") mm "z"
```

in macro i got a tree:

```
Apply(Select(Ident(M), newTermName("Obj")),  List(Apply(TypeApply(Select(Select(This(newTypeName("immutable")), scala.collection.immutable.List), newTermName("apply")), List(TypeTree())), List(Literal(Constant("a")), Literal(Constant("b")), Literal(Constant("c"))))))
```

and an actual type `M.Obj`
is it possible without tree traversal extract a `List`?

Comment: Where's the `str` identifier in your arguments? Can you add an example of the macro's usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this  might not answer your question directly but in soon to be released 2.11 you'll be able to use quasiquotes to do all the hard work for you:

```
 val q"${s: String}" = other.tree
```

Comment: @lito Quasiquotes are available in 2.10 with a [compiler plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html)

Comment: Unfortunately unlifting doesn't (yet) work in 2.10 version of quasiquotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to extract the `String` from `other`, use

```
val otherStr: String = other.tree match {
  case Literal(Constant(str: String)) => str
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an obvious way. Is it possible without tree traversal extract a `List`?